# How to set VSCode to find the python interpreters sync by Dropbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, dropbox, visual-studio-code

I face a strange python virtual environment synchronous problem which might be not solved yet, and I have tried to find lots of related issues and technical words on the web.

**Here is the situation**

A and B are two laptops of me, and I built python virtual environments by using the command of virtualenvwrapper: "mkvirtualenv temp_1" on A at first. The absolute address of `temp_1` on A is `D:\Dropbox\python\envs\temp_1`, then it was automatically synchronized by Dropbox after being built.

Due to the synchronous setting of my Dropbox, it of course was synchronized and downloaded to B when I using B.

However, the Visual Studio Code installed on B can not find the python interpreter in the python virtual environment `temp_1` and always show the message

```
no python interpreter is selected
```

[image: error message]

while it can definitely be detected by the VS Code installed on A. Besides, the VS Code always only show the original python interpreter which is installed under `C:\` (`C:\Python\Python38-32\pyton.exe`) but in the temp_1 no matter how I set the absolute address of python interpreter to `python.pythonPath:` in `settings.json` of User setting and Workspace setting in VS Code on B.

If I chose the "original python interpreter" in VS Code on B, the problem that IDE can not find or recognize python interpreter could be solved owning to the VS Code on B will rewrite the interpreter address to `python.pythonPath:`. But, relatively, the same problem will shows on A after the rewritten files of `temp_1` being synchronized by Dropbox to A; hence, instead, the VS Code installed on A can not find and recognize the python interpreter in `temp_1` and shows the issue message and provides the original python interpreter under `C:\` of A when I return to use VS Code installed on A to code the python program files.

**Below is the solution I use temporarily**

Every time when I change using the laptop, I have to use the command of `virtualenvs` to create a virtual environment that is Exactly identical to `temp_1` in the virtual environment by itself. For example:

```
D:\Dropbox\python\envs> workon temp_1
(temp_1) D:\Dropbox\python\envs> virtualenv temp_1
```

After doing the steps above, the VS Code on A (or the laptop where files of the virtual environment are overwritten by Dropbox synchronization) can find or recognize the interpreter which was built in `temp_1` but the original python directory under `C:\`

Even it works, it is very annoying to me (or anyone). Is any solution can synchronize the python virtual environments and let them be found or recognized by VS Code install on different laptops with Dropbox?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you placed your code inside the virtual environment which isn't the proper place to put it. I would create a directory for your project, put your code in there, and then install the virtual environment into a subdirectory (e.g. `.venv`). Then you can set `.vscode/settings.json` to have a `"python.pythonPath: ".venv/Scripts/python"` value.